# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString functions in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make some javascript code from a website (footlocker.com) run in my a webView in my app when a button is pressed. How can I format this code so that when I press a button in my app, it will run the javascript code from the website so it is pressing a button for me pretty much. I believe I have to do this with the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString string but I am not sure. Please let me know if you have any ides.

And also, how can I get the javascript code of any website? I think its inspect element but I am not sure.

This is the javascript code I got from the inspect elemen of the button I want the app to press from footlocker.com (Add to cart button) but I am not sure if this is correct:

```
<input title="Add To Cart Button" tabindex="869" name="pdp_addtocart" value="Add To Cart" type="submit" class="active_step">
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's an HTML element. That isn't JavaScript code. I think what you're looking for is a little more involved than this...

Comment: How can I find what I am describing?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're describing. Are you attempting to get a UIWebView to update when a UIButton is pressed, or are you attempting to have the contents of your UIWebView change based on an action taken within the UIWebView?

Comment: I am trying to make a button in my app click a button within a webView automatically

Comment: That `<input>` tag submits a form. Find the ID of the form and call `document.getElementById("myForm").submit()` as the javascript that you send to the web view in response to your `UIButton` press.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the document.getElementById code please? I am not familiar with this... And also how do I find the ID of the input form?